# SparkContext' has no attribute 'builder error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to registertemptable from dataframe in pyspark.
code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.builder.appName("Python Spark").getOrCreate()
sqlCtx = SQLContext()
data = sqlCtx.read.csv("D:/Customers_v01.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
data.registerTempTable("data")
spark.sql("SELECT * from data").show()
```

but this is throwing error as AttributeError: type object 'SparkContext' has no attribute 'builder'.

The data looks like

```
CM,503004,(d$όνυ$F|'.h*Λ!ψμ=(.ξ;      ,.ʽ|!3-2-704              ,.ʽ/8μAθr                    ,(d$όνυ<<*έθr                ,C51,CN-511450
```

Am i missing something. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to use this way.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
     .getOrCreate()
```

Once you created the spark session you can read the csv this way.

```
data = spark.read.csv("D:/Customers_v01.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.....is it possible to add this logic to current code. df['column_name'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii'). kindly suggest

Comment: I have added the sample data with unicode.Thanks a ton

Comment: Thank you very much, can we filter it with where clause on dataframe. kindly suggest

Comment: You mean filter all columns containing non ascii character?

Comment: Filter Records if any of the column contain non ascii character, and push to other temptable.